# Glyphicons < and > appearing as E079 and E080 in little squares in the Bootstrap 3 Carousel

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have used the design found at http://getbootstrap.com/examples/carousel/
I have downloaded the versions of CSS and JS used on the page:

CSS
http://getbootstrap.com/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css
http://getbootstrap.com/examples/carousel/carousel.css

Javascript:
https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js
http://getbootstrap.com/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js
http://getbootstrap.com/assets/js/docs.min.js

The scrolling is working ok and my image changes are fine.
I have put the files together on a windows machine.

Any ideas as to what I am doing wrong?

```
<a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span></a>
<a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span></a>
```

Comment: Could we please see some code or a link to the page?  It's going to be much harder to diagnose the problem without context.

Comment: It sounds like it might be an issue with a missing class on the `glyphicon-chevreon-*` nodes, but as Surreal suggests, post the code you're using. We'll be able to help more if we can see what you're working with.

Comment: I have the file I downloaded with minimal changes. Lo and behold it has the same issue.  I will add it to the question...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had the same problem when I used the carousel gallery and bootstrap. Turns out I had not included the Glyphicons Halflings fonts in my site root folder. After I created a fonts folder and copied the required font files. The square box with E079 as replaced by the left < arrow.

Answer (score 3):

I was resolving issue with downloading fonts written inside bootstrap.min.css line 2464
`@font-face {
    font-family: 'Glyphicons Halflings';
    src: url(../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot);...`

Answer (score 2):

If you are seeing squares that reflect the Unicode address of the glyph, e.g. `E079`, you may not have properly attributed the bootstrap classes on the `<span>` for the icon. You need to make sure that your span contains both the reference to the glyphicon web font (e.g. `glyphicon`) as well as the icon you're intending to use (e.g. `glyphicon-chevron-left`, and `glyphicon-chevron-right`).

For instance, from the example referenced above, the chevron's are identified as follows:

```
<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  ...
  <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
  </a>
  <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
  </a>
</div>
```

If the classes are the same, as you indicate in your edit, inspect the elements with a browser tool like Firebug or Chrome (or Safari's) developer tools. Here you should be able to see what classes are currently applied to the elements and determine why the fonts are not rendering correctly. The first thing to look for is whether or not the class which defines the font family for the *Glyphicon Halfings* font is present on the same element as the chevron spans. E.g. you want to see the following class:

```
.glyphicon {
  position: relative;
  top: 1px;
  display: inline-block;
  font-family: 'Glyphicons Halflings';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: 1;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}
```

along with...

```
.glyphicon-chevron-left:before {
  content: "\e079";
}
```

Reported for the `<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>` node.

If you don't see both of those, the bootstrap CSS isn't being included or read properly.

Finally, if you're still having problems I would recommend starting a new `.html` document and paring down the example from Bootstrap's gallery as much as possible. That way there is less markup and less going on, and as you begin to disassemble it and put it back together you may find a missing quote, or some other typo which is causing the error that you're seeing.

Comment: I have added the code to the question.  Yours is formatted better but the classes are the same.

Comment: I'm just sorry it hasn't helped you more. :( If you can find some way to host the code and the changes you've made that aren't working, I'll be happy to take a look at it again. Until then, best of luck!

Comment: Where you have content: "\e079"; in the CSS, I see the the little square with E079 in the quotes when viewing the CSS through Firebug. The .glyphicon class is similar enough: 
.glyphicon {
    display: inline-block;
    font-family: 'Glyphicons Halflings';
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 400;
    line-height: 1;
    position: relative;
    top: 1px;
} 
I wonder where the font data is actually coming from...

Comment: So, in Firebug, I'm not surprised you're seeing the squares (Firebug isn't necessarily aware of the font, so it just renders that address glyph). When the page is rendered though, if the browser supports web fonts (which Firefox does), those glyphs from the the **Glyphicons Halflings** font should display. Since the font family is defined earlier in the bootstrap CSS. You've certainly got an interesting problem. :)

Comment: Hmmm on the page itself it notes: "Note: If you're viewing this page via a file:// URL, the "next" and "previous" Glyphicon buttons on the left and right might not load/display properly due to web browser security rules." What security rules?...

Comment: @JohnHartley the only thing I can think of right now is CORS (Cross-origin resource sharing), read more about it [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-Origin_Resource_Sharing) beyond that it may just be local access restrictions?

Comment: And the answer? There is a required fonts directory that was missing. The error in Firefox Web Developer Extension said: @font-face {   font-family: "Glyphicons Halflings";   src: url("../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot?#iefix") format("embedded-opentype"), url("../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff") format("woff"), url("../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf") format("truetype"), url("../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.svg#glyphicons-halflingsregular") format("svg"); }

Comment: @JohnHartley glad you found a solution and it was as simple as a missing resource!

Answer (score -1):

I too had same problem try this one:

make sure this file `"your_template\less\variables.less"` contains the right path.

Change path at:

```
"@icon-font-path: '../../plugins/system/t3/base-bs3/bootstrap/fonts/'";
```